# Cannot launch Enthought Canopy (64-bit) in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, enthought, canopy

I downloaded the Enthought Canopy installer and ran it. The install finished with no problem, created ~/Canopy, etc..

However when I try to launch the application for the first time, I get the following error (line-breaks added before '1' and '9' for prettification; [U] is a non-displaying unicode character):

```
robert@robert-Q550LF:~/Desktop$ bash canopy-1.1.0-full-rh5-64.sh
    [installation legalese snipped]
robert@robert-Q550LF:~/Desktop$ ~/Canopy/canopy
/home/robert/Canopy/bin/python:
    1: /home/robert/Canopy/bin/python: [U]ELF[UUUUUUU] not found
/home/robert/Canopy/bin/python: 
    9: /home/robert/Canopy/bin/python: Syntax error: ")" expected
```

Has anyone successfully installed Enthoughy Canopy on Ubuntu Saucy Salamander? Did you encounter a similar issue?

Comment: Just to check -- is this a 64- or 32-bit installation of Ubuntu? (If 32-bit Ubuntu, then of course you must install 32-bit Canopy, to match.)

Comment: I installed the 64-bit version of Canopy on the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. It ran beautifully for about a week and now fails to start, as above.

Comment: You are not actually running the installation shell script repeatedly, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the solution to your problem, but i need to run as root to the directory i install canopy, i.e., /root/Canopy/canopy

i need to run in Terminal (OS: Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.0.4 LTS),

Command runs as follow:

root@yovan-Aspire-4741:~# cd /root/Canopy

root@yovan-Aspire-4741:~/Canopy# canopy

Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)" 
/root/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits/etsconfig/etsconfig.py:373: UserWarning: Environment variable "HOME" not set, setting home directory to /tmp
  (environment_variable, parent_directory))

DEPRECATED: traits.has_traits.**call**, use "adapt(adaptee, protocol)" instead.

Hope this helps.
Regards
Wan

Comment: Thanks, I actually reverted my Linux install to 13.04 since at that time Saucy Salamander was still in beta. It worked fine for a week but then it crashed when I was doing a big sparse matrix manipulation. Haven't been able to de-install or re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed the 64 bit Canopy on a 32 bit system, as mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/361013/canopy-ide-unexpected-error

You need to install 32 bit Canopy on a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was working originally, you would probably have been able to have reset by deleting `~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit` and `~/.canopy`, and restarting the app. But by now, version 1.1.0 is 8 months old, lots of fixes since then. I suggest that you delete these directories, and also install the current version 1.3.0 (or 1.4.0 within the next week).

Comment: I did delete those directories. The problem came when I tried to reinstall, it said it needed to clear the old install first.

Comment: That's fine, sorry I assumed that as part of installing the current version. By default that would be in `~/Canopy` -- just delete it.